# Is commit necessary after DML operation on table using simple sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it necessary to run the `COMMIT` command after a DML operation in SQL Developer? For example, I performed the following `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE TAB1 
SET TBX_TYP='ZX'
WHERE TBX_TYP IN(SELECT TBX_TYP
                  FROM(
                   SELECT DISTINCT TBX_TYP
                    FROM TAB1
                       ORDER BY 1 ) 
                 WHERE ROWNUM=1);
```

Then when I tried filtering columns, I found that nothing was updated.

Comment: Try to execute the query from the `where` clause does it return any rows?

Answer (score 2):

The `COMMIT` instruction is necessary if you want you changes will be available for other users/connections, for example:

Session1:

```
SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.

SQL> truncate table ttt;

Table truncated.

SQL> desc ttt;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)

SQL> insert into ttt values('one');

1 row created.

SQL> select col1 from ttt;

COL1
--------------------
one
```

So new data is available in current session.

Session2:

```
SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> select col1 from ttt;

no rows selected
```

But another session can't see this data. So let's commit it:

Session1:

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Session2:

```
SQL> /

COL1
--------------------
one
```

Now this value is available for both sessions.

But commit also is necessary to store data in you data files.

For example let's add a new row to the `ttt` table but don't commit it:

Session1:

```
SQL> insert into ttt values('two');

1 row created.

SQL> select col1 from ttt;

COL1
--------------------
one
two
```

Then let's shutdown the database abnormally and the start it again

Session2:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
Fixed Size                  2260048 bytes
Variable Size             616563632 bytes
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes
Redo Buffers                5517312 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL>
```

Then reconnect Session1 and look at the `ttt` table:

```
SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> select col1 from ttt;

COL1
--------------------
one
```

As you can see, the database doesn't store uncommited data in its data files.

Comment: Need to add this: **DON'T** `COMMIT` more often than you really need. The database has to do some complicated work to merge your changes into the rest of the database, and using `COMMIT;` too often wastes resources. You need to, as a programmer, decide what your "unit of work" is (for example, it might be 3 `insert` queries, 2 `delete` queries, then an `update`, *then* a `commit`). Use `commit` each time your "unit of meaningful work" is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Add Commit after every DML(update, delete, insert) command.

Comment: This answer does not take into account the importance of considering a 'unit of work' - see comment by @SlimsGhost for more details.